# Blur (unfocus) window

Tags: windows, gtk, window, pygtk

Quick question: How to blur (unfocus) a window in PyGTK, without creating or setting the focus on other window? I can't find (or I don't know where to search) a solution for this in PyGTK documentation...

Comment: the 'blur' event is called `focus-out-event`, if that helps!

Comment: Do you mean making a window transparent? You can use the `Window.set_opacity(opacity)` method: http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-opacity

Comment: @Nandakumar - no, I'm not talking about the visual effect, I'm talking about the same thing you get when you click outside of the current active window.

Comment: I think that depends on the window decoration system, not on PyGTK.

Comment: It depends of the window manager, of course, but the idea is that I just want to make the current window inactive, I don't just want to simulate a unfocused window or something

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assuming a Gtk.Window named 'win'...
win.set_focus(None)
```

For further detail, see documentation at http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-focus

> If focus is None the window's focus widget is unset.